# Object not found when knitting in R markdown

Tags: r, object, dataset, r-markdown

I'm trying to run some simple calculations and plots for a dataset, but when I try knitting or running these in markdown I get an error:

Error in plot(USMortality) : object 'USMortality' not found
Calls:  ... withVisible -> eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> plot
Execution halted

And this is what I tried running in RMarkdown:

```
plot(USMortality)
```

Using other datasets worked and running calculations related to this dataset (USMortality) in the console worked (specifically plot() worked, but other functions worked as well). It seems to just not be working when in RMarkdown. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need to load the package that has it. Perhaps `lattice`?

Comment: How did you create the `USMortality` object in the first place? Note that RMarkdown files are compiled in new R sessions. They cannot see any of the global variables in your workspace. All variables used in the RMarkdown file must be created and defined in the file itself.

Comment: It came from the `lattice` package IRTFM mentioned, which I have loaded. I think the solution may be to use `require(lattice)` in Rmarkdown. I'll update when I get a chance to try that

Comment: twas what I thought needed to `require(lattice)`